# Resize font with screen resolution without using @media query

Tags: html, css, fonts, resize, font-size

This code is working.

```
<style>
h1{ font-size:8.5vw;}
</style>
<h1>Heading</h1>
```

But this code is not working.

```
<style>
h1{ font-size:8.5px;}
</style>
<h1>Heading</h1>
```

**Question:** I want to resize font with screen resolution like this. http://css-tricks.com/examples/ViewportTypography/ -> (minimize screen resolution with mouse to check).
When I use font in `VW` like `font-size:7.5vw;` it works properly. But When I use font-size in `PX` like `font-size:40px;`it not work.

Comment: pixel is a fixed unit. It can't be dependent on screen resolution or on viewport size (unless you set a bunch of different mediaqueries which define a different font-size for each breakpoint)

Comment: Any other solution to do this. Can I do this by using any other unit of size ?

Comment: Yes I agree with @Fabrizio Calderan

Comment: `Screen resolution !== viewport width`. Then use `vw` units if they work or use a set of mediaqueries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible trick is using javascript to detect window's resolution and to set the font size property of the desired elements:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function autoResizeFont()
    {
        var value = function_of(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.getElementById('my_container').style.fontSize = value +'px';
    }
    window.onresize = autoResizeFont;
    autoResizeFont();
</script>
```

Where `function_of` is a function to be implemented that computes the value of the font size in pixels from the window size.

Another solution using JQuery:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        if ($(window).width() > THRESHOLD_VALUE) {
            $('*').removeClass('small-font').addClass('big-font');
        } else {
            $('*').removeClass('big-font').addClass('small-font');
        }
    });
</script>
```

This solution sets the appropriate class of all HTML elements depending on whether the window's width is greater or smaller than a threshold value. An example of `small-font` and `big-font` definitions could be:

```
.small-font {font-size: 10px !important}
.big-font   {font-size: 14px !important}
```

Comment: How to apply this on <h1> Heading </h1>

Comment: In JQuery, the selector to use is $('h1') instead of $('*')

Comment: In plain Javascript: document.getElementsByTagName("H1"). This returns an array of all H1 elements.

Comment: Another option is giving an `id` attribute to the desired H1 tag and then use document.getElementById()